# Can the Lucky feat be used on attacks made against an Echo Knight's Echo?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, class-feature, fighter, echo-knight

So, the question is regarding the Lucky Feats 2nd use.

> You can also spend one luck point when an attack roll is made against you. Roll a d20, and then choose whether the attack uses the attacker’s roll or yours.

Would that function as the Echo? Since the Echo is technically also you, but from a dying timeline that didn't happen.

*Matt Mercer: An Echo Knight is able to tap into those dying timelines and temporarily pull a version of themselves and use it to fight alongside them.*

This is also slightly supported by the fact that all the echo's rolls from attack rolls to saving throws is modified as if it were your real body's rolls.
What are people's thoughts about this?

Or is it as simple as "If I have the Lucky Feat, well so does my Echo."

Clarification on the Sentinel Feat part:
"When you hit a creature with an opportunity attack, the creature’s speed becomes 0 for the rest of the turn."

combined with the Echo's:
"When a creature that you can see within 5 feet of your echo moves at least 5 feet away from it, you can use your reaction to make an opportunity attack against that creature as if you were in the echo's space."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### In general, your echo cannot use your feats.

First, from the [description of the echo knight subclass](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#EchoKnight), the echo is not “you”:

> This echo is a magical, translucent, gray image of you.

It is only an image of you.

Second, the class feature description of the echo outlines everything the echo is able to do. The echo uses *your* saving throw bonus only because the feature description says so explicitly.

So when the [lucky feat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/lucky) says,

> You can also spend one luck point when an attack roll is made against you

It means that *you* have luck points to spend, and *you* can spend them when *you* are targeted with an attack. Your echo is not you and doesn’t have any luck points to spend since the class feature description says nothing about your echo accessing your feats.

In contrast, the echo knight’s feature description specifies that *you* are making an opportunity attack:

> When a creature that you can see within 5 feet of your echo moves at least 5 feet away from it, you can use your reaction to make an opportunity attack against that creature as if you were in the echo's space.

Since your are making the opportunity attacks, you would trigger the feature of the [sentinel feat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/sentinel) that says:

> When you hit a creature with an opportunity attack, the creature's speed becomes 0 for the rest of the turn.